# Не запускается код kivy python 1.11.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Вот мой код:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label


from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'weight', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')

class CalculatorApp(App):

    def build(self):
    
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', padding = 25)
        gl = GridLayout(cols = 4, spacing = 3)
        
        bl.add_widget(Label(text = "0"))
        
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '7'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '8'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '9'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = 'X'))
        
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '4'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '5'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '6'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = 'X'))
        
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '1'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '2'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '3'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '+'))
        
        gl.add_widget(Widget())
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '0'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '.'))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text = '='))
        
        bl.add_widget(gl)
        
        return bl

if __name__ == 'main':
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

вот что выдает консоль http://imgur.biz/image/WQhX

версия python 3.7.9
ОС винда 10

Comment: Никто не будет разбираться в картинках. Выложите код нормально

Comment: а зачем переоткрывать? чтобы снова закрыть с указанием другой причины?

Answer (score 4):

Вот если бы Вам дали картинки, много бы вы о коде сказали? Предполагаю, что строчка:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
```

должна выглядеть так:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Не запускается, так как имя "main" не находит.